# Cookies not available when not use 'www' in url

Tags: url, cookie

I am using SharePoint 2010. There is one cookie that the application creates upon first visit to the site.

If I go to `http://www.sharepointsite.com`, the cookie is created no problem.

After it is created, I go to any page directly without the 'www' in the url (ie. `http://sharepointsite.com/site/Pages/page1.aspx`), and the cookie that was created is not there, and gets created.

If i navigate to the same url with 'www' in the url (ie. `http://www.sharepointsite.com/site/Pages/page1.aspx`), the cookie is there.

Is there any reason why my cookies would show up for `http://www.sharepointsite.com`, but not `http://sharepointsite.com`?

Answer (score 2):

By default cookies are scoped to the *EXACT* host you provided. The subdomains you provided are different. You can explicitly define that a cookie is good for the whole domain by using a domain directive while setting the cookie. An example of this is available here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain

Comment: I tried that, however it creates two cookies one for sharepointsite.com and www.sharepointsite.com, and when I update the cookie with a value, it does not set. Also, that is for subdomains. Setting a cookie without specifying it's domain should set for with and without a dot, by default from what I remember.